# How to Give fixed size for a Form Text Field Laravel 4

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, textbox

I want this Form Text Field to have a fixed size..

```
![{{Form::text('Name',$org!=null ? $org->name : '', array('id'=>'orgName','class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Orgnization name'),Input::old('Name'))}}][1]
```

It Extends throughout the page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by either;

- Add a class next to `form-control` and use CSS to style it
- Add `'size'=>'30x5'`to the properties array (this will produce 30 cols and 5 rows)